# Can I do filename pattern matching in a bash script?

Tags: bash, filename

Can I do filename pattern matching in a bash script?

`test` is a directory with the following files ...

```
bob@bob-laptop:~/test$ ls  
exclude  exclude1  exclude2  include1  include2
```

From the command line, if I want to exclude some of the files, I
can do ...

```
bob@bob-laptop:~/test$ echo !(exclude*)  
include1 include2
```

but, if I put that command in a script (named `exclude`) ...

```
bob@bob-laptop:~/test$ cat exclude  
echo !(exclude*)
```

when I execute it, I get an error ...

```
bob@bob-laptop:~/test$ ./exclude  
./exclude: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('  
./exclude: line 1: `echo !(exclude*)'
```

I've tried every (I think) variation of escaping some, all or
none of the special characters and I still get an error.

What am I missing here? If I can't do this, would someone
please be so kind as to explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line at the top of the script. Without a shebang line, the kernel doesn't know that your script must be executed with bash. See [Shell script fails: Syntax error: “(” unexpected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45781/shell-script-fails-syntax-error-unexpected/45784#45784)

In addition, the `!(…)` syntax is not enabled by default, for historical reasons (earlier versions of bash did not support it). You need to set the `extglob` option.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
echo !(exclude*)
```

Comment: thanks very much!

now I'm trying to figure out why I couldn't find this answer that was posted a mere two hours later

Comment: @BobBowden There is another answer on this question, posted about 2 hours earlier than mine and later deleted by its author. It is correct but less complete than my answer.